# Screen is not moving to another screen

Tags: c#, xaml, telerik, windows-phone-8.1

I am using radHubTile on my Tapped and I have an event which uses the following code:

```
private void hubNotes_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MagicListsPage));
}
```

I don't understand why it's not moving the sheet to the second page. I am using Windows Universal Phone 8.1

Comment: Formatting. Punctuation.

Comment: Is hubNotes_Tapped event getting raised?

Comment: @igrali sovled this so i did was the base event causing triouble sorry